# Hibernate organization

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, annotations

I try to work with Hibernate. Everything is going OK but I have a problem when I want annotate subclass. I want to have in each table ID and FK (id) from subclass

```
@Entity
@javax.persistence.Table(name="person")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Person{

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="id_person")
protected int id_person;

@Column(name="name")
protected String name;  ....
```

subclass

```
@Entity
@javax.persistence.Table(name="worker")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="id_person")
public class Worker extends Person {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="id_worker")
protected int id_worker;

@Column(name="salary")
protected int salary ; ...
```

I want to have unique ID from worker because this class

```
@Entity
@javax.persistence.Table(name="driver")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="id_worker")
public class Driver extends Worker{

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="id_driver")
protected int id_driver;

@Column(name="category")
protected String category; ....
```

How is possible when I save one driver to get new ID for person in table person,

new ID for worker and ID from that person in table worker ,

new ID from driver and id from that worker in table driver ... ?

In this case, I got error `org.hibernate.mapping.JoinedSubclass cannot be cast to org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass` , but if I move ID from subclass , then I don't get ID for that class ...

Comment: That doesn't make sense. If Worker extends Person, that means that a worker **is a** person. Since a worker is a person, and this person already has an ID that identifies it among all persons (inclusing workers, drivers, etc.), then the person ID is the worker ID, and worker should thus not have an ID. It would be completely redundant. If you try to find a person by ID, and the person with this ID happens to be a worker, then you'll get a Worker instance.

Comment: I think , maybe later , if I will have bigger database and many tables it's good to every row in every table have unique ID , because queries and faster search . That's my opinion , but I started with hibernate and I trust you and work how you say ... Thanks ...  And , is it makes sense to my first thinking for unique every row and faster search ?

Comment: @zexco2 Bigger database won't make any change, but you need to specify a dialect  used by the queries. Hibernate is used to abstract from the database and use objects on the Java side.

Comment: @zexco2 the tables **will** have a primary key. The primary key is the person ID.